# Cannot reach 4G-router past IPcop firewall

Tags: networking, router

I have been using IPCop for several years and versions. My current setup is

```
    ISP(WAN) -> 4G usb modem -> Dovado Pro -> IPcop v2.1.9 ->LAN
```

For IPcop Dovado is the RED network (WAN). Recently my double ethernet mobo I used for IPcop failed, so I replaced it with a newer and more energy efficient one. Before the mobo change I could reach my Dovado's web interface from LAN - now I cannot even ping it. Apart from that IPCop seems to work as before...

I have assigned the same IP scheme that I had before:

```
   The Dovado's IP towards IPcop is 192.168.157.1
   IPcop's RED IP is 192.168.157.152 (static)
   IPcop's GREEN IP is 192.168.50.254 
   so my LAN is 192.168.50.0/24
```

Any suggestion how to solve this irritating problem?
Thanx!

Comment: Sorry guys.... After five days with the above symptom/problem, today it is gone (the problem) and everything is back to normal - I can log in to my Dovado's web interface from LAN.
No idea what caused the problem and/or what happened during last night that corrected it - it wasn't me anyway, I was asleep. ;-)